# Is there an effective way to load a lot of text in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

UITextView is causing my App to slow down because it holds a lot of text. I was wondering if there is some kind of third party library that can load more text effectively?
I am using attributedText to hold all of the text. If there is a better way please let me know. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

```
 textView.attributedText = attributeStr;
```

Comment: Are you sure this line is causing slow down? Maybe the only thing what cause it is creation of attributeStr. To avoid blocking UI, you could consider creating attributeStr in background thread and then assign it to textView.attributedText on main thread.

Comment: Define “a lot of text”.

Comment: I'm running into same issue. My string has a size of 27K. I'm setting it in viewDidLoad. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Really?  It worked fine on me. Please check this out on how I implemented my UITextView.The  HELP_STATIC_CONTENT there is a constant variable that holds static texts for my Help screen which contains lot of texts (about  500 lines).

```
UITextView *lblHelp = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, self.view.frame.size.height - 20)];
[lblHelp setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lblHelp setEditable:NO];
[lblHelp setSelectable:NO];
lblHelp.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
lblHelp.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
[self.view addSubview:lblHelp];

NSString *string = HELP_STATIC_CONTENT;
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraphStyle.alignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;
[paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:3]; 
[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
[attrString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

[attrString endEditing];
lblHelp.attributedText = attrString;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only a part of the text, you can directly change it with the `textStorage` property e.g:

```
[textView.textStorage addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor yellowColor] range:range];
```